# Handling forms with class table inheritance models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, class-table-inheritance

I would like to use `form_for` except I have class table inheritance models using the `citier` gem. They are defined as such:

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
    # calories:integer
    # color:string
end 

class Apple < Fruit
    # is_sauce:boolean
end

class Banana < Fruit
    # is_peeled:boolean
end
```

The problem is that I want the first part of my form to fill out attributes for my `Fruit` model. Then depending on a select field on what type of fruit (`Apple`, `Banana`), I then want to fill out attributes for that particular model yet I still want validations with the `form_for` helper. Any suggestions on how I can approach this... or additional clarification? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was asking for the model before creating the form. Then using many partials.